# Can I use a `robots.txt` file for a subdirectory on my school's domain?

Tags: robots.txt

I own some webspace which is registered with a University. Google has unfortunately found my CV (resume) on the site, but has mis-indexed it as a scholarly publication, which is screwing up things like citation counts on Google Scholar. I tried to upload a `robots.txt` into my local subdirectory. The problem is that google ignores this file, and instead uses the rules listed for the school domain.

That is, the url looks like

> www.someschool.edu/~myusername/mycv.pdf

I have uploaded a robots.txt, which can be found here

> www.someschool.edu/~myusername/robots.txt

And Google is ignoring it and instead using the `robots.txt` for the school's domain

> www.someschool.edu/robots.txt

How can I make Googlebot ignore my CV?

Comment: I think `robots.txt` might only be honored for the root path of a given *domain*... :( In this case it's *the same domain*, just with a different *path*.

Comment: Note that what you have there is a *subdirectory*, not a *subdomain* - `robots.txt` works just fine for subdomains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, `robots.txt` is defined to be whatever you get when you `GET /robots.txt`, so you can't use it for your subdirectory.

What you can do is use the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header, if you can use custom `.htaccess` files. Here's [Google's documentation on `X-Robots-Tag`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

Comment: As far as I can tell, sitemaps just tell the search engine which content is important. They don't seem to let you tell search engines to ignore content outright.

Comment: @John: Yeah, you're right. Apparently you can also control indexing with a `<meta>` tag, which you can't use because it's a PDF, or with a HTTP header. Can you use a custom `.htaccess` file on your University homepage?

Comment: I've removed the wrongness and added a link to the relevant docs.